# How to run an Overpass-API `around` query incrementally excluding already searched area?

Tags: performance, overpass-api

I have to find some types of POIs around a given coordinates. Ideally, I want to find the nearest one of such POI around the given coordinates.

To meet my requirement I can search with either `around`

```
[out:json];
(
  node["public_transport"="platform"](around:500,48.2,16.3);
);
out body center qt;
>;
out skel qt;
```

or *approximately* with `bbox`

```
[out:json][bbox:48.19,16.29,48.21,16.31];
(
  node["public_transport"="platform"];
);
out body center qt;
>;
out skel qt;
```

My strategy to search quickly is to start search in a small area (short distance or smaller bbox), if I could not find anything then I will increase the search area. I search incrementally until something is found or a hard distance limit is reached.

I am not sure if Overpass-API implementation has done some performance tricks like cache of previous result.

Every time I increase search area I still search the previous smaller area. With `bbox` I can somehow split it and avoid already searched area, but I do not know I can achieve it with `around`.

How can I use `around` method to increase search area without covering old searched one?

update: to focus on search procedure itself. I will ignore the rate/resource limiting, latency, and so on, since I can eventually run my own instance instead of querying public one. I could perform queries in parallel or do some load balance among instance but it is just further optimisation options.

Comment: You need to define your performance requirements / expectations first. Concrete values, please. Also, do you run one or many requests? You might hit some rate limiting, which delays responses, and makes the server appear to be slow. Your question doesn't provide those crucial details.

Comment: @mmd you are right. I update the question and would focus on just `around` question. The overall system or application performance is not my main point.

Answer (score 1):

After some research I still cannot find any solution to have such `around` query as I would like to have.

My current alternative solution is to use overpass API to query ALL possible desirable POIs from a specific area and then perform indexing/searching (e.g. with KD-tree) in my application.